# Populate a field with a value from a field from another page on another domain

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to create a field which would pull values from another field on another page that's located on another domain.

There are 2 fields: #div-one (on page-one) and #div-two (on page-two)

There are two pages: page-one (on domain "One.com") and page-two (on domain "Two.com")

When a user opens page-one I want #div-one to pull the value that is inside #div-two on page-two located on Two.com.

I found this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pullValueFromPageTwo(){
    var val = $('[#div-two]').text();
    $('#div-one').val(val);
}
</script>
```

But I didn't found any clue of how to use that code to pull a value from another page and domain using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

JSONP is another method for circumventing same origin policies.   jQuery 1.5 has improved support for it.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP

Answer (score 0):

jQuery on `One.com` can not access `Two.com` because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

However, *if* they were on the same domain, something like this should work...

```
var otherPage = $('body').load('/echo/html/', function(html) {

    var text = otherPage.find('#div-two').text();

    $('#div-one').html(text);

}),
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer! And if I want to pull a value from another page on my own domain (page-two is also on One.com) - is that possible?

Comment: Thank you, I will test different combinations and let you know about the results!

Answer (score 0):

Or you could get the data from Two.com with something else (YQL {http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/} for example) and then work with the results using javascript (as it returns XML this is very possible)..

An example query that you can put in the address bar to see the results of:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20xpath=%22/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/ul/li/h2%22%20and%20url=%22http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/%22;&format=xml&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env
```

You can then get the value from Two.com on One.com with a little bit of ajax and do what you want with it.